# Word for 'fire burning in your heart' type of feeling?

Tags: word-request

When you're trying to sleep but are occupied, you might feel that there's a 'fire burning in your heart'. This is a rather strong feeling as if an 'intense passion'.

More accurately, your heart is beating rapidly, and you feel that a warm...wave? is emanating out of your heart.

Is there a word to describe such a feeling?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a single word that specifically describes the "fire burning in your heart" type of feeling that you get *while you are trying to sleep*. There are phrases that you could use to describe such a feeling more generally.

You could say

**[fired up](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fire%20up)**

> 3: to fill (someone) with energy or enthusiasm
> *The coach fired up the players with a pep talk.*
> —usually used as (be/get) fired up
> *We were fired up for the concert.*

**[pumped up](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pump-up)**

> 1: to cause (someone) to become energized, excited, or enthusiastic
> *His music always pumps me up*

**[galvanize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/galvanize)**

> 1: to cause (people) to become so excited or concerned about an issue, idea, etc., that they want to do something about it
> *However, the tragic passing of his mother, who was only 47 years of age, galvanized his warrior spirit during a torturous training camp.*

It could very well be that what you are feeling is **a rush of [adrenaline](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adrenaline)**

> NOTE: Adrenaline is used in both technical and nontechnical contexts. It is commonly used in describing the physiological symptoms (such as increased heart rate and respiration) that occur as part of the body's fight-or-flight response to stress, as when someone is in a dangerous, frightening, or highly competitive situation, as well as the feelings of heightened energy, excitement, strength, and alertness associated with those symptoms. In figurative use, it suggests a drug that provides something with a jolt of useful energy and stimulation.
>
> *He felt a rush of adrenaline as he parachuted from the airplane.*
> *The fans were jubilant, raucous, their adrenaline running high.* — W. P. Kinsella
> *My reputation was as a single-day racer; show me the start line and I would win on adrenaline and anger, chopping off my competitors one by one.*— Lance Armstrong

Comment: I should have clarified that it need not be 'during sleep'. Oops. Just to give a possible context...